# Haskell vs. erlang: difference in foldl?

Tags: haskell, erlang, fold

I've noticed there's a difference between Haskell and Erlang when it comes to `foldl`.

For `foldr`, both languages return the same results:

```
foldr (\x y -> 2*x+y) 4 [1, 2, 3] -- returns 49
lists:foldr(fun(X, Y) −> X+2∗Y end, 4, [1,2,3]). % returns 49
```

But the return values for `foldl` are different:

```
foldl (\x y -> x+2*y) 4 [1, 2, 3] -- returns 16
lists:foldl(fun(X, Y) −> X+2∗Y end, 4, [1,2,3]). -- returns 43
```

How can this difference be explained?

Comment: The order of arguments to the first argument of `foldl` and `foldr` seems to be different in Haskell: `foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b` and `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`.

Comment: `2*x+y` vs `X+2*Y` -- is that intended?

Comment: @chi Very observant, it turns out I mixed these two! However, the problem still exists, except that it's now exactly other way around... `foldr` behaves the same, but `foldl` returns a different number.

Comment: That supports Dogbert's suggestion: Erlang `foldl(f,x,l)` seems to be equivalent to Haskell `foldl (flip f) x l` -- `f` takes the arguments in a different order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are confusing yourself by not simplifying your fold function.

**fold left, Haskell**:

```
Prelude Debug.Trace> foldl (\x y -> trace("x:"++show x++" y:"++show y) $ x+y) 4 [1,2,3]
x:4 y:1
x:5 y:2
x:7 y:3
10
```

**fold left, Erlang**:

```
1> lists:foldl(fun (X,Y) -> io:format("x:~p y:~p~n", [X,Y]), X+Y end, 4, [1,2,3]).
x:1 y:4
x:2 y:5
x:3 y:7
10
```

**fold right, Haskell**:

```
Prelude Debug.Trace> foldr (\x y -> trace("x:"++show x++" y:"++show y) $ x+y) 4 [1,2,3]
x:3 y:4
x:2 y:7
x:1 y:9
10
```

**fold right, Erlang**:

```
2> lists:foldr(fun (X,Y) -> io:format("x:~p y:~p~n", [X,Y]), X+Y end, 4, [1,2,3]).
x:3 y:4
x:2 y:7
x:1 y:9
10
```

From this, it's clear that in Haskell, the `foldl` function will be passed `(Accumulator, Element)` while the `foldr` function will be passed `(Element, Accumulator)`.  On the other hand, both functions in Erlang will be passed `(Element, Accumulator)`.